# Format JavaScript Date object to specific format

Tags: javascript, date

I have a JavaScript `Date` object. I am submitting this to a web service. The web service expects the format to be something like this: `2014-01-01T00:00:00Z`. Unfortunately, I do not even know what that format is called. It looks like its `[Year]-[Month]-[Day]-T[Hours]:[Minutes]:[Seconds]Z`.

I suspect that the `Z` means something. However, I do not know what. Is this a standard `Date` format? If so, is there a way I can easily convert my `Date` object to this format? Or, do I need to manually build it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not even know what that format is called.

It's one of the forms defined by [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

On any modern browser, you can get that form using the `toISOString` method, except it will include milliseconds, which your example doesn't. The endpoint you're sending to may not care; if it does, a simple `replace` can get rid of them:

```
var str = dt.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}/, '');
```

If you need to support IE8, you'll need a polyfill.

Another option is to use something like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), which offers all kinds of formatting options.

Example of `toISOString` and `replace`:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var str = dt.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}/, '');
snippet.log(str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! Phenomenal answer. Thank you for being so thorough.